# How can I convert the width of SVG from percent to pixel?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I created a vector image and set the width and height percent to 100%, like that:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
svg.setAttribute('id', 'idsvg');
svg.setAttribute('width', '100%');
svg.setAttribute('height', '100%');
```

Now I want to create a rectangle with the position of '100% - 20px' but it doesn't work, because 100% is not a number. How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. Do you just want to subtract `20px` from `100%`?

Comment: yes (100% - 20px) but it didnt work because 100% is not a number and i get 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this **you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**. This will let you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values.

So your code should be something like this:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
svg.setAttribute('id', 'idsvg');
svg.setAttribute('width', 'calc(100% - 20px)');
svg.setAttribute('height', '100%');
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind, you can't use `calc(100% - 20px)` for `height` in your particular case because the result will be unknown. So it's better to use `calc(100vh - 20px)` or `100%` itself.

Comment: but how and where should i define calc() ?

Comment: @SMario There is no need to define it, it is CSS built-in function, so it will calculate the result automatically in run time.

Comment: i am doing everything in the javascript site and it shows me that 'calc' is not defined. Because i dont use CSS?

Comment: @SMario You should certainly put it inside the quotes (`''`) just like what I provided. Also, you are creating an SVG then somehow you will put it into the DOM, so when it appears in DOM, the object model will take care of the rest.